# Use jQuery to read dynamically created content

Tags: jquery

I am something of a novice when it comes to jQuery but thanks to another stackoverflow member I have some code which allows users to click a radio button and have it add a table row filled with the text of the radio button link they clicked on. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$('.addRow').click(function() {
    var tr = $(
        '<tr><td class="cat"></td>' 
        + '<td class="sel"></td>'
        + '<td><textarea name="cmo-paragraph[' + count + ']">Click to edit (id ' 
        + count 
        + ')</textarea></td></tr>'
    );

    $('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append(tr);
    tr.find(".cat").text($(this).closest("li.category").attr("title"));
    tr.find(".sel").text($(this).closest("li.select").attr("title"));
    count++;
});
```

Here's a snippet of the radio list:

```
<li class="category" value="1" title="Chronic Pain Referral">Chronic Pain Referral
    <ul>
        <li class="select" title="Chronic referral">
            <input type="radio" class="addRow" id="radio1" name="modalities" value="1">
            <label for="radio1">Chronic referral</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This will successfully add a row to a table each time with the 'category' and 'select' table cells filled with 'Chronic Pain Referral' and 'Chronic referral' respectively on the frontend.

The problem is I want to be able to submit this information in a form to save to a database. I can iterate through the rows thanks to the 'count' variable so I can capture the textarea data but the values of the 'category' and 'select' cells for each row currently aren't passed.

I attempted the following code change but it appears not to work:

```
$('.addRow').click(function() {
    var tr = $(
        '<tr><td class="cat"><input type="hidden" class="hiddenCat" name="category[' + count + ']"></td>' 
        + '<td class="sel"></td>'
        + '<td><textarea name="paragraph[' + count + ']">Click to edit (id ' + count + ')</textarea></td></tr>'
    );

    $('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append(tr);
    tr.find(".cat").text($(this).closest("li.category").attr("title"));
    tr.find(".hiddenCat").text($(this).closest("li.category").attr("value"));
    tr.find(".sel").text($(this).closest("li.select").attr("title"));
    count++;
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. I see you capturing a bunch of things with find(), but you don't do anything with them in this code. Maybe try simplifying your question and show only the relevant code.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried debugging your code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, maybe a picture will help. Take a look here: http://i.imgur.com/C3iMJkQ.png    Right now the 'category' and 'select' values from the unordered list on the left is added to the table under 'group' and 'item' when a user clicks on the radio button, but this is purely cosmetic. What I want to do is also pass those values along in a hidden form field so I can submit their values to a database

Comment: Have you tried setting the new 'group' and 'items' value with `.val(xpto)`instead of `.text(xpto)`? The `.val` must be passed. Inspect the element and you will see its value to be empty if you only set the `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I didn't explain my situation very well, but I did come up with the answer I was looking for which I'll share.

```
$('.addRow').click(function() {
        var tr = $(
        '<tr><td class="cat"></td>' 
        + '<td class="sel"></td>'
        + '<td><textarea name="paragraph[' + count + ']">Click to edit (id ' + count + ')</textarea></td><td><input type="text" name="catText[' + count + ']" class="hiddenCat"></td></tr>');
        $('.mainTable > tbody:last').one().append(tr);
        tr.find(".cat").text($(this).closest("li.category").attr("title"));
        tr.find(".hiddenCat").val($(this).closest("li.category").attr("title"));
        tr.find(".sel").text($(this).closest("li.select").attr("title"));
        count++;
      });
```

I had to add another table cell to put in the hidden textbox, because it was being overwritten in the cell I originally placed it. Now when a user clicks on the "Chronic Pain Referral" option, a hidden textbox captures that so I can pass that information along in a form.